# Can I get 1000 images from any image search engine for education/research purpose?

Tags: data-request, api, machine-learning, images

I'm researching on machine learning system that learns to recognize items based on image search results from search engine. After I searched around I found that Google and Bing Image Search api allow only small number of images and doesn't allow script/bot to makes the search request.

I want to get about 1000 images for one item. Does anyone know is it possible to do this using Google, Bing or any search engine? Though free search engine is preferred, but any paid one is also welcomed.

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the API, you can use a bulk downloader* tool to collect images from a Flickr group

- Example of [bulk downloader tool](http://thetechreviewer.com/tech-tips/how-to-initiate-bulk-download-entire-flickr-photo-album/)
- Example of [Creative Commons group (pool)](https://www.flickr.com/groups/creative_commons-_free_pictures/pool/)
- [Wikimedia Commons Public Domain Archive](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:CC-PD-Mark)
- [Other ideas](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10332/bulk-download-of-public-domain-images)

*instead of a bulk downloader tool, you can use [wget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4602181/2327328)

```
wget -r -P /download/location -A jpg,jpeg,gif,png https://www.flickr.com/groups/creative_commons-_free_pictures/pool/
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for late respond. Flickr seem to be the only source that I can use in my research currently. However, I will continue to find more image search engine for my research.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the [Flickr API](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/) -- specifically, by doing a search for [Creative Commons](https://www.flickr.com/creativecommons/) pictures.

The API endpoint you want is probably [Public Feed](https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/photos_public/).